How to use SQL formatting in MyBatis XML files in IDEA
I am using IntelliJ IDEA, and we have some code-styles (even default ones) for SQL structures.
How can I make IDEA recognize SQL in Mybatis XML files as SQL. It does not recognize them and formats them badly.

The problem was because of namespace of MyBatis XML files.
In File | Settings | Editor | Language Injections | MyBatis sql|select|insert|update|delete config the default Namespace value was http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibatis-3-mapper.dtd|http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd.
But in my XML files the namespace was https://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd (it was https not http). So by adding this namespace to configuration, the problem solved.
